# How could I realize library coexistence of different versions?

Tags: python, pip, setup.py

While I want to use library A in version v2, my referenced package B is using library A version v1. How should I deal with such case?

One approach is, after `pip install`, rename package and rename module in my script. AFAIK pip in the current version 8.1.2 doesn't allow us to rename package when installation. But this approach is not cool, I think.

Is there any other better way to realize coexistence of library different version?

Comment: Why do two different parts of your package need different versions of the same thing? Can't you upgrade one or downgrade the other? What's the breaking change?

Comment: Thank you for reaction. In fact, package B is not mine, it is distributed one. On the other hand, my scripts make use of specific feature to library A in version v2.

Comment: Could you give a less vague example?